# Creating a CalDAV event with status confirmed is not propagated on Android (through DAVx5)

Tags: calendar, caldav

When I create an event in Nextcloud Calendar (or through Thunderbird Lightning) while forcing the status as **confirmed**, it is not propagated correctly to Android through CalDAV.

I am sure that the event has a good status since when I record it, it looks like that:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//IDN nextcloud.com//Calendar app 3.3.2//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20221228T155220Z
DTSTAMP:20221228T155234Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221228T155234Z
SEQUENCE:2
UID:bf4dd5a9-9bb3-400d-8c72-3c9ab250f218
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:20221221T120000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:20221221T123000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test4
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Paris
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I sync it on my phone running Android 10 (Fairphone 2 running [/e/ OS](https://e.foundation) 1.6, I guess it is done through [DAVx5](https://www.davx5.com) which is included in /e/), the status is not there anymore and all calendar apps ask me if I will participate in the event.

The event seen in Android does not have the status anymore (where my email is replaced by `MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN`):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//Calendar//foundation.e.calendar
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:3cc1eec6-4d2a-494b-99ee-e69613b49e26@foundation.e.calendar
DTSTAMP:20221228T160252Z
SUMMARY:test4
DTSTART:20221221T110000Z
DTEND:20221221T113000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN:mailto:MYMAIL@MYDOMAIN
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any idea what I did in the wrong way or where (Nextcloud/Android/e/DAVX5) to find or report the bug if it is one?

By the way, everything is working fine when done the other way (event created under Android and synced to Nextcloud server): status is **confirmed** in the created event.